# rake db:seed doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

I have made a small `db/seeds.rb` file:

```
web = Website.find_or_create_by(id: 1) do |w|
  w.website = "http://example.dev/"
  w.banner_msg = "Hey! Banner message!"
  w.signup_msg = "Wahey! Sign up message!"
  w.bg_col = "#333"
  w.txt_col = "#EEE"
  w.btn_col = "#999"
end

pub = Publisher.find_or_create_by(id: 1) do |p|
  p.phone = "021 111 1111"
  p.website = web
end

User.find_or_create_by(id: 1) do |u|
  u.email = 'email@email.com'
  u.password = 'password'
  u.first_name = 'Joe'
  u.last_name = 'Bob'
  u.publisher = pub
end

User.create(id: 5, email: "hello@ds.dfs")
```

When I run `rake db:seed`, the terminal simply accepts the command and presents a new line, no error message, no "rake abort!", nothing.

When I check the fields in Rails Console, there's nothing there. What's happening?

Comment: I believe you are doing it in production environment? Try `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed` in this case.

Comment: @arogachev running `rake db:seed` on production is kind-of dangerous, why would someone wants to seed a production db with fake data? but your approach may work, although it's better with `RAILS_ENV=development` instead, any news @Mirror318 ?

Comment: @Mirror318 also, try adding `puts "Users created: #{User.all.count}"` to see if it's working and actually creating the users when running the rake command.

Comment: @bntzio It depends. In some cases seeds may contain initial data which is not fake. But as for this specific question, you are right.

Comment: @arogachev you're right in that the environment is important, but I was running everything in dev, not production. @bntzio I was typing `User.all` into `rails c` to check whether anything was happening. You're suggestion would work, but I guess my complaint is that error messages should come up without needing manual setup like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find_or_create_by!(attributes, &block)` which is like `find_or_create_by`, but calls `create!` so an exception is raised if the created record is invalid. [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by%21)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out that

**1)** The colors were breaking, they are not allowed to be 3 digits here, had to be the full 6.

**2)** My chain of relations was wrong. I had `user` has a `publisher`, which has a `website`, when the models were actually setup where `website` has a `publisher` which has a `user`.

My annoyance here is there were absolutely no error messages. I had to copy and paste the contents of `seeds.rb` into Rails Console, then all it said was `rollback`, so I had to enter `user.errors` to see the errors for the `user`, and like wise for the other models.

Does anyone have suggestions on better error feedback for this kind of situation?

Comment: Appending the  `--trace` option when you call `rake db:seed` can be helpful for trouble shooting.